# Django create report

Tags: python, django, report

```
class Beverage(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    beverages = models.ManyToManyField(Beverage, through='LocationStandard')
    location_number=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class LocationStandard(models.Model):
    beverage=models.ForeignKey(Beverage)
    location=models.ForeignKey(Location) #elim this or m2m
    start_units=models.IntegerField()
    fill_to_standard=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    order_when_below=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

class Order(models.Model):
    location=models.ForeignKey(Location) #elim this or m2m
    beverage=models.ForeignKey(Beverage)
    units_ordered=models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)
    order_delivered=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

How can I generate a report that will get me an HTML table with all locations on the x-axis and all beverages on the y-axis. The main thing I am struggling with is just what to query that I can pass the template that I can loop over. Thoughts?

Comment: I've run into a similar but slightly simpler scenario myself where I needed dates on the Y and categories on the X. Solved it with some pretty brutal data munging.  +1, interested to see if there's a good solution.

Comment: BTW @jasongonzales, are you workin at columbia university ?

Comment: not at columbia, funny, why do you ask?

Comment: Because they do a lot of Django there, and I answered a lot of questions like this for people from that place. Just wanted to know if it was yet another one. It would have been funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get them in one query, but you can make something like that (don't want to setup a whole env to test, so use it as a clue, not a working solution):

```
# you can't do order_by in a template, either do them in the view, or 
# make methods in the model, or make it the Meta default ordering

# print the header, and make sure we got a list of all beverage cached
beverages = Beverage.objects.order_by('name') 
for beverage in beverages:
   print each cell of your header

# print a row for each location
locations = Location.objects.all()
for location in locations:
   print the location name table cell
   location_beverages = iter(location.beverages.order_by('name'))
   # for each beverage, we print a cell. If the beverage is in the 
   # location beverage list, we print a checked cell
   # we use the fact that queryset are iterable to move the cursor
   # only when there is a match
   cur_bev = location_beverages.next()
   for beverage in beverages:
        if beverage == cur_bev:
            print checked table cell
            cur_bev = location_beverages.next()
        else:
            print empty table cell
```

The intermediary variables to store querysets are very important, as they allow you to benefit from Django queryset cache.

With Django 1.4 or more, you can replace:

```
locations = Location.objects.all()
```

By:

```
locations = Location.objects.prefetch_related('beverages')
```

To get a serious perf boost.

Comment: So, just to be clear, since I am writing to a Django template, I should probably substitute pushing the values to a dict, rather than actually printing them, yes?

Comment: Except the `.order_by('name')`, you can do all this in the template. Just loose the parenthesis and use {{ value }} to print a value among the HTML code.